# Aptana remote files code assist

Tags: autocomplete, aptana

I'm a long time Zend Studio user who is attempting to transition to Aptana.

A lot of the projects I work on aren't actually projects inside of Zend, I just use the remote files section of Zend and use git/svn on the remote filesystem (there are reasons for doing this rather than storing it locally, but that's not relevant to my question).

Is there any reason that I can't get code assist/autocomplete working in Aptana, specifically for custom classes/functions? For example, if I have the following:

```
file1.php
function myTestFunction($var) {......

file2.php
$test = myTes{ctrl+space}
```

I don't get any code assist popup to auto complete the function name (even if file1 is currently open in another tab).

This functionality does exist in Zend, I haven't attempted it in Eclipse/PDT but know it doesn't work in either standalone Aptana, or the Eclipse plugin.

Am I missing something, or is there no way to achieve this? If it's not possible then it's pretty much a deal breaker for me. We're too far down the line to start using 'Projects', and code assist is one of those things that you really start relying on :)

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio treats remote files differently. Unlike files in a workspace project, remote files are not getting indexed, therefor, you will not get Content-Assist for functions on file1 from file2.

The main reason for that is performance. Indexing a project involves reading the content of each file in the project, so in cases where the project is located remotely, the performance hit is problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess for my current usage I'll need to stick to Zend (although performance on Zend Studio is no worse than Aptana on my PC). It would be nice if there was an option to enable this (not necessarily index all remote files, but be intelligent enough to know if a file I currently have open in another tab is included in my current file), but I assume I'm in a minority and it won't happen :)

Comment: @jsmith Open a ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa I'm sure there are other developer that will enjoy this enhancement ;)